# error in fxml TableView

Tags: java, javafx-2, fxml

I create FXML file that describes the table

```
 <AnchorPane fx:id="AnchorPane" id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="ru.pfr03.sprut.client.UnittypeController"> 
      <children> 
        <TableView fx:id="unitTypeTableView" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0"> 
          <TableColumn prefWidth="100.0" text="Код"> 
          </TableColumn> 
          <TableColumn prefWidth="125.0" text="Наименование"> 
          </TableColumn> 
        </TableView> 
      </children> 
    </AnchorPane>
```

hereinafter called this fxml

Parent p = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("UnitTypeTable.Ffxml"));

Controller for FXML :

```
public class UnittypeController implements Initializable { 
    @FXML 
    private TableView<Unittype> unitTypeTableView; 

    @Override 
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) { 

    }   
}
```

and I have exception:

```
Exception in Application start method 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) 
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) 
        at com.javafx.main.Main.launchApp(Main.java:453) 
        at com.javafx.main.Main.main(Main.java:537) 
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method 
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source) 
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(Unknown Source) 
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(Unknown Source) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) 
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: javafx.scene.control.TableView does not have a default property. 
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(Unknown Source) 
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(Unknown Source) 
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source) 
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source) 
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source) 
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source) 
        at ru.pfr03.sprut.client.Sprutclient.start(Sprutclient.java:40) 
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(Unknown Source) 
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(Unknown Source) 
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$3.run(Unknown Source) 
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method) 
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(Unknown Source) 
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$2$1.run(Unknown Source) 
        ... 1 more
```

how to fix this error? 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the `TableColumn`s with `<columns>  </columns>` in the fxml file.